# JNA - Set resource Path

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am trying to set up JNA to talk to a custom DLL i have but to no avail

It keeps saying it is looking in the resource path in the lcoation /target/classes/

I was wondering is it possible to add a resource location where it can pick up my DLL?

My code is as follows

```
System.setProperty("jna.debug_load", "true");
System.setProperty("jna.debug_load.jna", "true");

System.setProperty("jna.platform.library.path", "C:\\Development\\dll\\");

Native.loadLibrary("customDLL", CustomDLL.class);
```

If I manually add the dll to the folder /target/classes/, the DLL loads as expected

I am using Eclipse Luna 32bit
JDK 1.7.0_65 32 bit
JNA 4.1.0

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JNA looks in the location specified by the system property `jna.library.path`, falling back to whatever path is in `java.library.path` otherwise (which is mostly set based on `PATH` from the environment).

You should make sure that eclipse copies the DLL to wherever the application will eventually expect to find it, and also ensure the eclipse properly sets `jna.library.path` to that location when launching your JVM.

Note also that any dependent libraries must either by on `PATH` or in the same directory as your target DLL.

See the [JavaDoc for NativeLibrary](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.0/javadoc/index.html?com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html) for other variations on where JNA can load your native library.