# Plate recognition using Java and tesseract, tess4j

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have a problem during compilation of the program. The code itself has no errors.

Program code:

```
    package plate;

import java.io.File;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;

public class OcrReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Me\\eclipse-workspace\\platerecognition\\picture.tif";
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();

        String fullText = tesseract.doOCR(new File(inputFilePath));
        System.out.println(fullText);
    }
    }
```

And the error after running the program:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer
    at plate.OcrReader.main(OcrReader.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Pointer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Which Java version?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_151"

Comment: You need the JNA library too.

Comment: I downloaded it in zip from github, and pastied it to my project tree. Still doesn't work. How should I import it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063614/jna-set-resource-path oh wait that was the paths used by JNA. Their github page seems to have plenty of documentation https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: I still can't run it, I think I added the JNA correctly, like other libraries.

Comment: That error message disagrees with your thinking.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's not working, so obviously you did something wrong. Time to hit the documentation again (or for the first time, if you didn't even read them).